# Argo Workflow SSO authentication programmatically

Tags: kubernetes, argocd, argo-workflows, keycloak-connect, argo

I need to authenticate ARGO workflows running in sso mode using keycloak provider.

Currently in my organization we are using keycloak as the authentication provider for all the application. We have requirement to invoke argo workflows from one of the application lets say Job_Service and this Job_Service will also be authenticated using keycloak before accessing any resources in it(Job_Service authentication is successful).

So to invoke Argo workflows from Job_service i am passing the same access token present in context but i'm getting below error.
**{
"code": 16,
"message": "token not valid for running mode"
}**

Can someone help me on this ?

**Note:**  I have provided all the configuration in argo ConfigMaps. Created secrets for keycloak's Client info in K8s as well .
I could able to successfully authenticate from ARGO UI(clicking on login through SSO and then redirected to keycloak ui for entering the credentials ). But i want to achieve the same through Java programetically.

Comment: Still no answer on this?. I don't think argo-workflows works well with Keycloak. Can you provide your sso settings (sanitized, obviously).